# Matplotlib interactive mode in Kaggle

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, kaggle

Is there any way to run a notebook in interactive mode in Kaggle?
In [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/joaopdrg/students-performance-in-exams-data-visualization/notebook?scriptVersionId=115680546), I'm getting errors with the get_window_extent method, and the images don't show correctly.